# Start and stop a program at specific time intervals

Tags: java

I am looking for a solution to start and stop a program at predefined time intervals.

A scheduler would do the required justice, but how could the same be attained without using a scheduler.

I could always write a block of code, which checks for the current timings and based on this i could make a decision, however executing this piece of code would consume additional resources and processing power, which is not required if the program runs for hours.

Any efficient suggestions/solution on how this could be attained?

Comment: on windows, you can simple use task schedular to launch your java app, without any code

Comment: [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduler.....

Comment: You want to schedule without a scheduler?

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to run actions to stop and start whatever needs stopping and starting at defined times.

Comment: Yes, i do not want to use a scheduler. i would rather have some kind of ticker in the code, which ensures the program gets terminated at the right time. The case should be same to start the program. I can always go for schedulers, but if there is any efficient way to achieve the same in a program, prefering this choice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer with following algorithm.

in timer.tick Method

- Stop Timer
- Perform Operation
- Start Timer

In Form Load

- Set Timer interval
- Set Timer Tick

This works with Winforms

Answer (score 0):

You wish to start and stop a program. If by program you mean an entire Java process I suggest that you use [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for Linux/Unix to define the timing and then invoke some start- and stop-script. Windows has similar capabilities by the use of the Task Scheduler.

Crontab example that starts a job at 11 and 16 every day.

```
00 11,16 * * * /home/someuser/bin/start-app.sh
```

If you wish to start a job from within a Java process I suggest that you use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and schedule a `TimerTask` that does the job for you.

However, I guess that both of the solutions above are technically *schedulers* that you did not want to use.